# can not set tabindex on angular ui-select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select, ui-select2, angular-ui-select

There is a angular ui-select dropdown on my web site. The angular ui-select is placed among other input fiedls(text boxes). Eventhough tabindex is set on the ui-select it is not working. the ui-select is on the form as the 4th element but when tabbing the input fields, it directly goes to the 5th element after tab out from the 3rd element. Can anyone tell me how to fix this please. I have googled it but could not find a satisfying answer.
The ui-select html code as follows

```html
<ui-select class="selecter-basic" name="Subject" tabindex="4" ng-focus="setFocus(4)" ng-class="{'warning': contactUsForm.$submitted && contactUsForm.Subject.$error.required }" ng-model="contactRequest.Subject" id="selectSubject" required>
  <ui-select-match placeholder="{{resourcesData.ContactRequestForm_SelectedValue_Default_Subject}}">{{$select.selected.Value}}</ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="subject.Key as subject in subjectList | filter: $select.search" value="{{$select.selected.Key}}">
    <span ng-bind-html="subject.Value | highlight: $select.search"></span>
  </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

following is how ui-select is rendered in the browser
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is `setFocus(4)` a custom function? If so change the `ng-focus` for `focus-on` that is implemented in the ui-select itself.

Comment: setFocus is an inbuilt function angular-ui-select. I have changed it to focus-on and tested it. But still the dropdown list is skipped.